# MP3 Encoding in Java

Tags: java, api, encoding, mp3

I need an OpenSource API in Java, which can encode *.wav and *.au formats to MP3 and vice-versa.

I have evaluated Java Sound API and [LameOnJ](http://openinnowhere.sourceforge.net/lameonj), but they do not meet my requirements and are not stable, respectively. Please suggest one that is free and platform independent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There may not be an adequate answer for you, yet, as the MP3 format requires the authors of decoder/encoders to obtain a license from the Fraunhofer Institute.

I think the the LAME library is distributed from a country that does not respect these IP issues, but it took a considerably amount of legal hackery to get this far.

For any other libraries - for example one written in Java, the authors need to get a similar license. Where cost is an issue - e.g. in an Open Source project, then this is enough of a disincentive to starting.

For more details see this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3#Licensing_and_patent_issues).

If LAME4J is not stable enough for you, then I'm afraid your options are probably:

- wait for Sun to license the format for the core JRE. This, I believe they have done recently, but I don't know of any release dates (perhaps to do with JavaFX)
- implement your own in Java, and pay the license. I wouldn't fancy this one, either.
- write your own Java wrapper to LAME, via JNA, or SWIG
- contribute to Lame4J.
- pick another format. OGG and FLAC are quite good, and relatively well supported.

Comment: Thanks Jamesh!
I guess I have found something similar to what you have suggested.

Comment: @Mohit: Would You mind sharing Your pick? It could be useful for others interested in the topic.

Comment: @Rekin: I see here I should have done that.. now since its been 3 years and I don't have that code anymore. I have completely forgotten what did I use. :(

Comment: I believe that patents are now expired: See https://www.iis.fraunhofer.de/en/ff/amm/prod/audiocodec/audiocodecs/mp3.html and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3#Licensing.2C_ownership_and_legislation

Answer (score 4):

Is has been some time, but Oracle/Sun has released MP3 support for JMF. This can be downloaded from the following url:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html

Adding it to the classpath will enable playback via the AudioSystem api.

Comment: That plugin only supports *decoding* of MP3, not encoding.

Answer (score 2):

The LAME4J uses the free but time-limited license and the unlimited license will cost you some money.

I've found the [Lamejb library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lamejb/) on the SourceForge, which requires only the lame binaries and works well without any additional licensing.

Comment: When you say "time-limited", how long do you mean it is?

Comment: When using LAMEOnJ you should manually renew your free license key every month. So you can't make a stable product with LAMEOnJ library without buying commercial key.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Process API](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) to invoke [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/)

SoX comes with source or as precompiled binaries for Windows and Mac.

Answer (score 1):

If you are searching a pure java version of lame, check out these sources:
http://jsidplay2.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jsidplay2/jump3r/

Answer (score 0):

The [Jave2 project](https://github.com/a-schild/jave2) is Java library that wraps FFMPEG and provides most of its functionality<sup>*</sup> through a rather useful Java API.

Pros:

- Useful Java API that is powerful and rather simple.
- FFMPEG binary is bundled in, so you don't have to manage an FFMPEG installation on your system.

Cons:

- Does not support streaming data: you have to work through temporary files: every conversion starts by storing all the content in some files on the system, getting FFMPEG to create new files for you, then reading them. This is not a deficiency in FFMPEG, more of a problem in Java where it is very hard to stream data to external processes<sup>**</sup>.

*) specifically around format conversion - the filter functionality is mostly not represented.

**) In Java, launching a process and connecting to its standard output and input is possible but not comfortable, and using named pipes (the BKM for piping AV to/from FFMPEG) is almost impossible, and even if you do manage to do that, Jave2 doesn't play well with that. I have a set of tools to workaround these problems, based on JNA, if anyone is intersted - I can share.