# How to convert .wav to .mp3 using Java?

Tags: java, audio, jar

I am looking for a library (.jar) which help me to convert sound file from .wav format to .mp3 format. Infact i want to write an application which reads .wav file from a specified location in linux, convert it to mp3 and save it in DB.

Kindly suggest any opensource java library which serve this purpose.

waiting for your feedback.

Regards,

Amir Iqbal

Comment: Please check - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997923/is-there-any-pure-java-way-to-convert-wav-to-mp3)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[**JAVE** (**J**ava **A**udio **V**ideo **E**ncoder) library](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/jave/) is what you are looking for:

> The JAVE (Java Audio Video Encoder) library is Java wrapper on the
>   ffmpeg project. Developers can take take advantage of JAVE to
>   transcode audio and video files from a format to another. In example
>   you can transcode an AVI file to a MPEG one, you can change a DivX
>   video stream into a (youtube like) Flash FLV one, **you can convert a
>   WAV audio file to a MP3** or a Ogg Vorbis one, you can separate and
>   transcode audio and video tracks, you can resize videos, changing
>   their sizes and proportions and so on. Many other formats, containers
>   and operations are supported by JAVE.

Comment: +1 for a new answer to an old question

Comment: Thank you very much guys. Definitely i will look into it. Thumbs up for you

Comment: It works and solved my problem. Thank you Mr. Eng. Fouad.

Comment: how about working with streams ?

Comment: Any non-GPL suggestions? thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/adrielcafe/AndroidAudioConverter

One of the easiest API found on github supports almost all formats but it will increase your APK Size