# How to Create A Silent Mp3 File that have a duration of 'x' seconds in android

Tags: java, android, audio, ffmpeg, mp3

I want to Merge two mp3 files with a silence in between two mp3 files. I can now merge Songs with my code, but i need to add silence of 'x' seconds between songs. and the 'x' needed to be a value user can change..
                    So the only thing i needed is a code to Create a silence mp3 file that have a duration of 'x' seconds ...

Comment: See answer for Java here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31800815/programmatically-create-mp3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the FFmpeg [anullsrc source filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#anullsrc):

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100 -t 5 out.mp3
```

The `-t` option defines the duration. This example will make a 5 second output.

Answer (score 2):

To merge in between, basic syntax is

```
ffmpeg -i first.mp3 -i second.mp3 -f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0:d=x \
-filter_complex "[0][2][1]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1" merged.mp3
```

where `x` should be replaced with the duration of the silence (in seconds).

Answer (score 0):

it looks like :

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc=r=44100:cl=stereo -t 5 -q:a 1 name.mp3
```

consumes almost 4x less disk space with the same frame rate, duration & stereo.